# mysql_upgrade failed - innodb tables doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, docker, innodb, mysqlupgrade

I am upgrading my mysql-5.5 docker container database to mysql-5.6 docker container. I was able to fix all other problems. Finally my server is running with 5.6. But when i run mysql_upgrade i am getting the following error.

ERROR:

```
root@17aa74cbc5e2# mysql_upgrade -uroot -password           
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306' '--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306' '--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.general_log                                  OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.ndb_binlog_index                             OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.slave_master_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_relay_log_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_worker_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slow_log                                     OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK

Repairing tables
mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_master_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_relay_log_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_worker_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'...
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 62: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 63: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 64: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 66: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 67: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 68: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 81: Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 82: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 83: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 110: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 111: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 112: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 128: Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 129: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 130: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1896: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1897: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1898: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1899: Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1900: Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1904: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1908: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Comment: Just spin up a 5.6 container.   Why use docker like a VM?

Comment: @user2105108, I am just starting new 5.6 container with the 5.5 container data volume. This was the part of data migration to the new version of MySQL.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is a known bug in MySQL 5.6, [it is documented here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67179).

According to the replies to the bug report, you can manually create the missing tables. The structure of the missing tables is provided as attachment [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=19725&bug_id=67179).

Steps to follow:

1. Drop these tables from Mysql:

   innodb_index_stats
   innodb_table_stats
   slave_master_info
   slave_relay_log_info
   slave_worker_info
2. Delete `*.frm` and `*.ibd` files for the 5 tables above.
3. Create the tables by running the following queries:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `innodb_index_stats` (
  `database_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `index_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `stat_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `stat_value` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sample_size` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `stat_description` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`database_name`,`table_name`,`index_name`,`stat_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin STATS_PERSISTENT=0;

CREATE TABLE `innodb_table_stats` (
  `database_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `n_rows` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `clustered_index_size` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sum_of_other_index_sizes` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`database_name`,`table_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin STATS_PERSISTENT=0;

CREATE TABLE `slave_master_info` (
  `Number_of_lines` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of lines in the file.',
  `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the master binary log currently being read from the master.',
  `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The master log position of the last read event.',
  `Host` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The host name of the master.',
  `User_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The user name used to connect to the master.',
  `User_password` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The password used to connect to the master.',
  `Port` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The network port used to connect to the master.',
  `Connect_retry` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The period (in seconds) that the slave will wait before trying to reconnect to the master.',
  `Enabled_ssl` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Indicates whether the server supports SSL connections.',
  `Ssl_ca` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The file used for the Certificate Authority (CA) certificate.',
  `Ssl_capath` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The path to the Certificate Authority (CA) certificates.',
  `Ssl_cert` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The name of the SSL certificate file.',
  `Ssl_cipher` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The name of the cipher in use for the SSL connection.',
  `Ssl_key` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The name of the SSL key file.',
  `Ssl_verify_server_cert` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Whether to verify the server certificate.',
  `Heartbeat` float NOT NULL,
  `Bind` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'Displays which interface is employed when connecting to the MySQL server',
  `Ignored_server_ids` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The number of server IDs to be ignored, followed by the actual server IDs',
  `Uuid` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The master server uuid.',
  `Retry_count` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of reconnect attempts, to the master, before giving up.',
  `Ssl_crl` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The file used for the Certificate Revocation List (CRL)',
  `Ssl_crlpath` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The path used for Certificate Revocation List (CRL) files',
  `Enabled_auto_position` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Indicates whether GTIDs will be used to retrieve events from the master.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Port`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Master Information';

CREATE TABLE `slave_relay_log_info` (
  `Number_of_lines` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of lines in the file or rows in the table. Used to version table definitions.',
  `Relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the current relay log file.',
  `Relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The relay log position of the last executed event.',
  `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the master binary log file from which the events in the relay log file were read.',
  `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The master log position of the last executed event.',
  `Sql_delay` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The number of seconds that the slave must lag behind the master.',
  `Number_of_workers` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Internal Id that uniquely identifies this record.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Relay Log Information';

CREATE TABLE `slave_worker_info` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_seqno` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_group_size` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_group_bitmap` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Worker Information';
```

4. Restart your MySQL server.
5. Run the [`mysql_upgrade`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html) script.

Comment: Thanks @jocelyn,  this seems to be a working solution. But i found simple way of doing this.

Comment: Hi, everytime I run the queries I get the following error from MySQL: 

#1813 - Tablespace for table '`mysql`.`innodb_index_stats`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.

And I can't DROP or DISCARD the tablespace :(

Comment: @Cray Same issue here. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I don't remember. But you could try to use the app MySQLWorkbench to do the job.

Comment: where do you delete the *.frm and *.ibd files from?

Comment: @Gustavo_fringe From MySQL data directory.

Comment: @jocelyn Thanks! i was able to find it.

Comment: @Cray  When that happens, you have to go into /var/lib/mysql/mysql  and manually remove those tables

i.e. rm -f slave_master_info.*

Then, restart mysql

Then, recreate the tables as above

Comment: Brilliant solution

Answer (score 9):

UPDATED Fix For: MariaDB 10

6 tables (includes gtid_slave_pos table)

note: MariaDB and MySQL have different GTID implementations that are not compatible with each other.

Use at your own risk.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `gtid_slave_pos`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gtid_slave_pos`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `gtid_slave_pos` (
  `domain_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `seq_no` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`,`sub_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Replication slave GTID position';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `gtid_slave_pos`
--

LOCK TABLES `gtid_slave_pos` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `gtid_slave_pos` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `gtid_slave_pos` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `innodb_index_stats`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `innodb_index_stats`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `innodb_index_stats` (
  `database_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `index_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `stat_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `stat_value` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sample_size` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `stat_description` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`database_name`,`table_name`,`index_name`,`stat_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin STATS_PERSISTENT=0;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `innodb_index_stats`
--

LOCK TABLES `innodb_index_stats` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `innodb_index_stats` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `innodb_index_stats` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `innodb_table_stats`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `innodb_table_stats`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `innodb_table_stats` (
  `database_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `n_rows` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `clustered_index_size` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sum_of_other_index_sizes` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`database_name`,`table_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin STATS_PERSISTENT=0;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `innodb_table_stats`
--

LOCK TABLES `innodb_table_stats` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `innodb_table_stats` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `innodb_table_stats` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `slave_master_info`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `slave_master_info`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `slave_master_info` (
  `Number_of_lines` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of lines in the file.',
  `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the master binary log currently being read from the master.',
  `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The master log position of the last read event.',
  `Host` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The host name of the master.',
  `User_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The user name used to connect to the master.',
  `User_password` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The password used to connect to the master.',
  `Port` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The network port used to connect to the master.',
  `Connect_retry` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The period (in seconds) that the slave will wait before trying to reconnect to the master.',
  `Enabled_ssl` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Indicates whether the server supports SSL connections.',
  `Ssl_ca` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The file used for the Certificate Authority (CA) certificate.',
  `Ssl_capath` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The path to the Certificate Authority (CA) certificates.',
  `Ssl_cert` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The name of the SSL certificate file.',
  `Ssl_cipher` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The name of the cipher in use for the SSL connection.',
  `Ssl_key` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The name of the SSL key file.',
  `Ssl_verify_server_cert` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Whether to verify the server certificate.',
  `Heartbeat` float NOT NULL,
  `Bind` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'Displays which interface is employed when connecting to the MySQL server',
  `Ignored_server_ids` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The number of server IDs to be ignored, followed by the actual server IDs',
  `Uuid` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The master server uuid.',
  `Retry_count` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of reconnect attempts, to the master, before giving up.',
  `Ssl_crl` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The file used for the Certificate Revocation List (CRL)',
  `Ssl_crlpath` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'The path used for Certificate Revocation List (CRL) files',
  `Enabled_auto_position` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Indicates whether GTIDs will be used to retrieve events from the master.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Port`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Master Information';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `slave_master_info`
--

LOCK TABLES `slave_master_info` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `slave_master_info` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `slave_master_info` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `slave_relay_log_info`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `slave_relay_log_info`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `slave_relay_log_info` (
  `Number_of_lines` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of lines in the file or rows in the table. Used to version table definitions.',
  `Relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the current relay log file.',
  `Relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The relay log position of the last executed event.',
  `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the master binary log file from which the events in the relay log file were read.',
  `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The master log position of the last executed event.',
  `Sql_delay` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The number of seconds that the slave must lag behind the master.',
  `Number_of_workers` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Internal Id that uniquely identifies this record.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Relay Log Information';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `slave_relay_log_info`
--

LOCK TABLES `slave_relay_log_info` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `slave_relay_log_info` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `slave_relay_log_info` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `slave_worker_info`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `slave_worker_info`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `slave_worker_info` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_seqno` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_group_size` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Checkpoint_group_bitmap` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Worker Information';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `slave_worker_info`
--

LOCK TABLES `slave_worker_info` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `slave_worker_info` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `slave_worker_info` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: I had same woes with missing tables and can confirm this worked for me on CentOS 7, jumping from MySQL 5.x to MariaDB 10.0.29. The upgrade appeared initially to have been seamless.

Comment: Lifesaver, also worked for me on Debian Stretch. This seems the simplest workaround. Don't know where exactly I went wrong. But I did a clean mysql install, removed it, installed MariaDB and imported my tables.
Seemed to work okay until I did a backup / sqldump

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this by deleting `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata*` files from the old container(5.5). I am copying content inside `/var/lib/mysql` directory of my old container(5.5) to the new container(5.6)  `/var/lib/mysql`. It's working if i skip copying `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata*` file.

```
  +---------------------------+
  | Tables_in_mysql           |
  +---------------------------+
  | columns_priv              |
  | db                        |
  | event                     |
  | func                      |
  | general_log               |
  | help_category             |
  | help_keyword              |
  | help_relation             |
  | help_topic                |
- | host                      |
+ | innodb_index_stats        |
+ | innodb_table_stats        |
  | ndb_binlog_index          |
  | plugin                    |
  | proc                      |
  | procs_priv                |
  | proxies_priv              |
  | servers                   |
+ | slave_master_info         |
+ | slave_relay_log_info      |
+ | slave_worker_info         |
  | slow_log                  |
  | tables_priv               |
  | time_zone                 |
  | time_zone_leap_second     |
  | time_zone_name            |
  | time_zone_transition      |
  | time_zone_transition_type |
  | user                      |
  +---------------------------+
```

Found that these are tables are added/removed in mysql-5.6. Copying/Using  old ibdata files leads to inconsistency with innodb tables and ibdata files. Though the .frm,.idb files are present, because of older ibdata its failing.

As mentioned in this [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67179#c392021), tried to delete that file and `mysql_upgrade` finished successfully.

> The ibdata* data files created by mysql_install_db are corrupt and must be trashed before starting mysqld !

Answer (score 2):

I got the "table doesn't exist" errors when trying to do a backup of my database.  I was able to use [FRANKLIN's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7092875/franklin) MariaDb script after performing these steps, required because of errors such as

```
ERROR 1813 (HY000): Tablespace '`mysql`.`slave_worker_info`' exists.
```

The steps:

1. Copy `engine_cost.frm` (arbitrary selection) as each associated
   `.frm` file
2. Execute `mysql -p mysql` to start the command interpreter.
3. Drop each table.
4. Quit the command interpreter.
5. Stop the database server.
6. Delete the orphan `.ibd` files.
7. Restart the database server.
8. Run FRANKLIN's script to create the missing tables.

Answer (score 2):

on MariaDB I found this solution, first remove old frm and ibd files and run mysql_upgrade with --force if required

```
cd /opt/zimbra/db/data/mysql/
mv innodb_*frm gtid_slave_pos.*frm ~
mv innodb_* gtid_slave_pos.* ~

~/common/bin/mysql_upgrade -S/opt/zimbra/data/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock -u root --password=$mysql_root_password --force
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional note to already given answers, if you happen to run MariaDB 10.x on Windows-based machine and experience the error in log file such as

`[Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade`

it is enough to run the tool from MariaDB's `bin` folder

`\mysql_upgrade.exe -u root --password=xxx --force`

and the tool will do it's magic to fix whatever needs to be fixed.