# Databases won't update after upgrade to MAMP Pro 4

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

After upgrading to MAMP Pro 4, I see two issues.

---

### 1. Hosts can't be found

Opening sites in the browser fail - sites can't be found. This isn't a database issue and looks to be an apache error

---

### 2. Mysql upgrade scripts fail

The MAMP Pro 4 MySQL upgrade scripts aren't working for me - I see the following errors for every table in each database.

```
database.btpagelist
Error    : Table 'database.btpagelist' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
```

So each time I open Mamp Pro it asks me to upgrade the databases.

---

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot and fix these issues?

Cheers

Ben

---

- Mac OS 10.11.6
- MAMP Pro 4.0.5 upgraded from Mamp Pro 3.5.2

Comment: Have you considered using AMPPS instead?

Comment: @Terry You know what? I'll give it a go as I'm tired of literally ZERO support for MAMP Pro (the paid version). Does it allow multiple hosts?

Comment: Do you mean different domains hosted on the same port? I've stopped using MAMP quite awhile ago, switched over to AMPPS and never had a problem since.

Comment: Tried AMPPS but it's way too different and kind of painful - don't have time. In the end I downgraded to 3.5.2 - path of least resistance etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to use these steps to downgrade to 3.5.2.

https://appsolute.zendesk.com/entries/111595586-I-want-to-revert-back-to-MAMP-PRO-3-52-

Very frustrating but as others have noted (and from my own experience) Appsolute have no interest in supporting their products (yes, even their paid ones).

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to MAMP 4.x with a clean install.  Some similar issues with the database being corrupt and trouble connecting to the local host.  Apache started and I had to manually add:

```
127.0.0.1 sscotti.local (my local machine name in sharing setup)
```

to the etc/hosts file to get it to point to my localhost for some reason.

Re:  Database, even with a clean install I'm seeing this sort of error, for five different tables:

```
mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
```

. . . .

Not sure if that is related to the system not upgrading the database or what, but I can import old databases and it runs.  Really annoying though, because otherwise it seems to work fine.  Contacted MAMP support, which has been responsive at times, so hoping that they will get back to me.  I've tried some other solutions, like deleting those tables and then adding them back with a script, but that doesn't seem to work on my system.  I think the 4.x release in general is a little buggy.  There may be some patch releases I hope that will fix outstanding issues.

There is a reference for my DB problem here:

[mysql-upgrade-failed-innodb-tables-doesnt-exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856155/mysql-upgrade-failed-innodb-tables-doesnt-exist)

but like I say, that actually doesn't work for my MAMP Pro install.  Hoping to hear back from support, or maybe a SO user.